# How to execute Robot Framework test scripts using IE,FF and Edge browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, robotframework, microsoft-edge

I have developed few browser based test scripts and trying to execute them with 4 different browsers - IE, FF, Edge and Chrome.

I have downloaded all browser drivers and placed them in 'drivers' folder in my project structure. Also, I have set the PATH of all these browsers.
All my web-based test cases are getting executed using Chrome browser, but they are failing when I run them using other browsers.

Here is my test script:

```
*** Setting ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variable ***
${Url_Link} <<<my url>>>

*** Test Cases ***
Launch page 
    Open Browser    ${Url_Link}    browser=ie
```

Below is the error message displayed every time I execute the test cases using IE,FF and Edge browsers :

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I have verified if there any instances of browsers running. But, there are no connections existing already.

Any suggestions to resolve this error would really help me to proceed in executing browser related test scripts.

Comment: Any chance Windows firewall blocking the requests?

Comment: Did you updated Selenium (and SeleniumLibrary)?

Comment: @Todor : I have verified, there are no blockers from firewall

Comment: @Helio : I have updated my question with sample script

Comment: Are you running your script as a different user?

Comment: @A.Kootstra: I am running all the scripts from Eclipse. Chrome browser was able to launch the page with no additional changes to the script.

Comment: Use a known public URL_Link reachable through your company proxy. Without using Eclipse, open a command window and show us the outputs of: "pip show selenium" "geckodriver --version" "IEDriverServer --version"

Comment: @Helio : Here is the command window output                                                                               C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip show selenium geckodriver --version
Name: selenium
Version: 3.13.0
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: robotframework-seleniumlibrary

Comment: @Helio:  C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip show selenium IEDriverServer --version
Name: selenium
Version: 3.13.0
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: robotframework-seleniumlibrary                                                                                        IF & FF failed to open public URL's, No issue observed with Chrome browser

Comment: > IE & FF failed to open public URL's
did you get the same error? You could have updated your question. You did not show the versions webdrivers. Can't say much.